# Data Validation of fields

Tags: html, excel, vba

In Excel I have one "GlobalConfig"-Spreadsheet where I can configure which fields in he other spreadsheets needs to be filled with integer, boolean or date value. For e.g.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6OQX.png)

Now I tried to make with VBA a data validation which picks up the spreadsheet and column, sets it as range and checks if all fields in this column are filled with the expected data value for e.g. integer. This check will be triggered by a action button. If the field is also marked as mandatory, it will be also checked if its empty or not.

Example for Integer Check:

```
With Range("XY").Validation 
 .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, _ 
 AlertStyle:= xlValidAlertStop, _ 
 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="99" 
 .InputTitle = "Integers" 
 .ErrorTitle = "Integers" 
 .InputMessage = "Enter an integer" 
 .ErrorMessage = "You must enter integer value in Field X in Column Y" 
End With
```

Example for Field Empty Check:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Sort _
    key1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Set currentCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Do While Not IsEmpty(currentCell)
    Set nextCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
    If nextCell.Value = currentCell.Value Then
        currentCell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Set currentCell = nextCell
Loop
```